# Remove observation based on occurrence in panel data

Tags: r, panel-data

I'm working with a panel data
and i want keep observations of id that the first time v_1=1 is not the first time of the specific id.
Kind of bysort command in stata
In the example i want to keep only 61312 obs and not 42848

Thanks

```
dd <- read.table(text="
id      year    v_1  
61312   2015    0    
61312   2016    0    
61312   2017    1    
61312   2018    1       
42848   2016    1       
42848   2017    0", header=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `group_by` and `filter` from `dplyr` to help with this task

```
library(dplyr)
dd %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter(first(v_1) != 1)
```

we use `group_by` so when we use `first()` it looks at the first values for each `id`

Comment: Ok thanks, 
It seems to be working. How R know to sort it by the year variable?

Comment: The data was already sorted by year. If that wasn't the case you could use `arrange(year)` before doing the `filter()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use -

```
subset(dd, id %in% unique(id)[v_1[!duplicated(id)] != 1])

#     id year v_1
#1 61312 2015   0
#2 61312 2016   0
#3 61312 2017   1
#4 61312 2018   1
```

`v1[!duplicated(id)]` keeps only the first `v1` value of each `id` and we select only those `id`'s which has that first value not equal to 1.